# Difference between $\|f\|$ and $|f|$

Tags: analysis, notation

Are these equivalent as i'm coming across what looks like a double modulus $\|f\|$? I have just been assuming that it is a modulus but I'm wondering if it is different in any way?

I'm coming across it in the triangle inequality over collections of continuous functions.

Comment: Usually we denote by $\|f\|$ the *norm* of a function $f$. Meaning that we choose something called a [norm][1] and evaluated it on $f$.


  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)

Comment: Where are you "coming across" this? Please edit your question to provide some clear context.

Comment: the notation $\|{\cdot}\|$ means "norm", and the notation $|{\cdot}|$ means "absolute value", what is a kind of norm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Just guessing a possible answer:** probably if you see these notation related to some space of (bounded) continuous functions then probably $\|{\cdot}\|$ is representing the supremum norm (it common notation is $\|{\cdot}\|_\infty$).

The supremum norm is defined as

$$\|f\|_\infty:=\sup_{x\in\operatorname{dom}(f)}|f(x)|$$

where $|{\cdot}|$ is the [absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value). Check if what I had written here make sense to you.

Comment: I have also seen this but what I am asking about doesn't have the infinity notation it is just $||f||$

Comment: @Jackie this is probably because the context make clear what norm is being used OR that the norm used is not important to the topic.

Answer (score 1):

The double modulus is the *norm* of a function, as the others have described. This varies from the modulus in subtle ways to extend to higher dimensions --- if you're reading a textbook, I would definitely suggest checking the introduction for a description on what they define the norm to be. The norm could be the *Euclidean norm*, which is the square root of the sum of the squared components for vectors, or the square root of the integral of the square of the absolute value of the function:
$$
||f|| = \left( \int |f|^{2} \right)^{1/2}.
$$

There are *many* definitions for the norm though, and if there is no subscript to it, then it should be taken from context from the norm is defined to be. Again, I would suggest checking the introduction to the text for the authors definition of the norm.